# How can I free pointers to string pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I would like to know how to free a struct that contains pointers.

```
struct tree {
    struct tree *p;
    char name[NAME];
    char *relation_name[RELATION];
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};
```

I would like to know what happen to `*relation_name[RELATION]` if I free the structure.
`*relation_name[RELATION]` points to some stings allocated with `malloc()`.
Should I free all the `*relation_name[RELATION]` and then free the structure?
Or if I free the structure everything is deleted from my memory?

Comment: free the strings before the structure. The *rule* is **every `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`) must have one corresponding `free()`.**

Comment: So if I want to change one of may string sould I do this?
free(tr->relation_name[i]);
tr->relation_name[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
strcpy(tr->relation_name[i],"new_string");

Comment: You can reallocate if you need to adjust size: `char *tmp = realloc(tr->relation_name[i], 11); if (!tmp) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); tr->relation_name[i] = tmp; strcpy(tr->relation_name[i], "new_string");` --- if size is already ok, just `strcpy()` will be enough.

Comment: Ok good to know.
My solution do waste memory or it's fine?

Comment: Your solution does not waste memory. It sometimes possibly wastes time when compared with the `realloc()` version by doing unnecessary free and allocation.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: **every `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`) must have one corresponding `free()`.**

So, in your case, you must `free()` the strings before the whole structure.

Supposing you do something like this

```
struct tree{
    struct tree* p;
    char name[NAME];
    char *relation_name[RELATION];
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
};

struct tree *x = malloc(42 * sizeof *x);
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
for (int k = 0; k < 42; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) x[k].relation_name[i] = malloc(100);
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

When it's time to release the resources you need to reverse the process

```
for (int k = 0; k < 42; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) free(x[k].relation_name[i]);
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
free(x);
```

Comment: upvoted, but your example only deals with the node, freeing a tree involves recusing on the child nodes too.